# Ayuda con consulta JOIN ON

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Necesito que en la tabla "merca" columna "TipoOperacion" me tome de la tabla coberturas el "nombre" del "idCobertura" y no me salga solo el "idCobertura"

Este ejemplo es el que tengo pero solo es con 2 tablas y quiero agregar la tercera(3)

```
SELECT  clientes.RazonSocial, clientes.RFC, clientes.Calle, clientes.Colonia, 
        clientes.Municipio, clientes.Estado, clientes.CP,
        merca.idViaje, merca.idCliente, merca.Cliente, merca.rfc, merca.moneda, 
        merca.mercancia, merca.importe, merca.TipoOperacion, merca.FechaAlta, 
        merca.detalles, merca.TipoTransporte, merca.FechaSalida, merca.FechaLlegada, 
        merca.folio, merca.porigen, merca.eorigen, merca.corigen, merca.pdestino, 
        merca.edestino, merca.cdestino, merca.Coberturas1, merca.Coberturas2, merca.Coberturas3, merca.Coberturas4, merca.poliza, merca.cuota, merca.prima, merca.gastosexp, 
        merca.iva, merca.total
FROM clientes join merca ON clientes.idCliente = merca.idCliente WHERE idViaje=".$idViaje);
```

Comment: No comprendo cual es el problema. en preguntas de este tipo es buena idea reducir el query a algo más pequeño (un [mcve]) e incluir algunos datos de ejemplo de entrada de las tablas relacionadas, la salida que estás obteniendo y la salida esperada. Un saludo.

Comment: Ya modifique la pregunta, espero y se entienda

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo tratas de obtener los datos de las tres tablas solo necesitas agregar un join mas espero te sirva

```
SELECT C.RazonSocial, C.RFC, C.Calle, C.Colonia, C.Municipio, C.Estado,
 C.CP, M.idViaje, M.idCliente, M.Cliente, M.rfc, M.moneda, M.mercancia, M.importe,
  M.TipoOperacion, M.FechaAlta, M.detalles, M.TipoTransporte, M.FechaSalida, M.FechaLlegada,
   M.folio, M.porigen, M.eorigen, M.corigen, M.pdestino, M.edestino, M.cdestino, 
   M.Coberturas1, M.Coberturas2, M.Coberturas3, M.Coberturas4, M.poliza, M.cuota,
    M.prima, M.gastosexp, M.iva, M.total ,Co.nombre
    FROM clientes C inner join merca M ON C.id = M.idCliente inner join Coberturas Co On M.idCobertura=Co.id
     WHERE idViaje=".$idViaje);
```

Comment: Amigo con tu consulta me sigue saliendo igual, me agrega el id y no el nombre